# If someone at a hedge fund reveals their firms position to someone else is it illegal to trade on or disseminate the information?

Tags: trading, legal

If someone at a hedge fund reveals the details of one of their positions to another person that doesn't work at the firm can the other person trade on, or disseminate, the information?

1. It's not like knowing Apple has to delay the release of the new iPhone by a month because Tim Cook told them
2. Hedge funds aren't public
3. It's not any type of guarantee that knowing a hedge funds position will actually make a trade go in a particular direction

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How far removed from source does one need to be to avoid Insider Trading?](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/89861/how-far-removed-from-source-does-one-need-to-be-to-avoid-insider-trading)

Comment: What makes a hedge fund's position in a stock insider information?

Comment: That's my question, after thinking about it it doesn't seem like it is. But was hoping to get opinions on that. I guess that's the real question. It's not like knowing Apple has to delay the release of the new Iphone by a month because Tim Cook told you

Comment: This is **definitely** answered by the question linked to by @user253751.  Read it, and your question will be answered.

Comment: It's really not. This is about hedge funds, not inside information about a company. Let's say you're in a stock and your friend tells you they are about to sell the stock. Is that illegal to act on? Of course not. If two hedge funds get together and one says I'm taking a position in Apple, is the other fund not allowed to?

Comment: If the information is immaterial, e.g. the hedge fund's position is small, then it isn't insider trading. Has to be material and non-public.